Automatically adding some words at the end of specific line
My English not well, so I will try explain my issue and I hope everyone can understand it...
My post have content like this:
[URL=https://abc.com/7ab4e24c328]MSK_10th_Anniversary_1080p.mp4[/URL] (800.89 MB)
[URL=https://abcdef.cc/1e3uetsrg]MSK_10th_Anniversary_1080p.mp4 - 800.89 MB[/URL]
[URL=https://123456.net/ziikv94zf]MSK_10th_Anniversary_1080p.mp4[/URL] (800.89 MB)

and it show on web like this:
MSK_10th_Anniversary_1080p.mp4 (800.89 MB)
MSK_10th_Anniversary_1080p.mp4 – 800.89 MB 
MSK_10th_Anniversary_1080p.mp4 (800.89 MB)

I want at the end of line have domain "https://abcdef.cc" will show specific words "(NOT SUPPORTED)" and line have domain "https://123456.net" will show "(WORKING)" like this:
MSK_10th_Anniversary_1080p.mp4 (800.89 MB)
MSK_10th_Anniversary_1080p.mp4 – 800.89 MB (NOT SUPPORTED)
MSK_10th_Anniversary_1080p.mp4 (800.89 MB) (WORKING)

I have a lot of posts, so I can't edit every single post and in the future, I want to change specific words at same time for many posts.
Thanks so much!!!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
